# Is there a 'non-destructive' way to make mix cds in iTunes?

Tags: itunes, music, playlist

I am looking to collect a set of songs from my iTunes Library and build a custom playlist to eventually burn onto a CD. I want the songs to be in a specific order and have the same album title when burned onto the mix cd... but I want to preserve the original album titles and track #s from their albums of origin in my iTunes Library.

Is there a preferred approach to the above scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create the new playlist.
2. Select all songs in the playlist and **create duplicates** (here: AAC version) of them.

   [image]
3. Rename the **Album** title for all tracks and set the song order via the **Get Info** menu entry.

   [image]
4. Burn the playlist and remove it.
5. You are save to **remove the newly created Album in the iTunes Library** (here: Testalbum) because you created duplicates earlier.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of is to

- restart iTunes with the Option key pressed to create a new library
- make sure that the new library stores the tracks in a different place than the original one
- import the relevant tracks from Finder into the new library
- rename, resort and burn
- close iTunes and delete the temporary library